# Button cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class ProjectActivity extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
        tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.TUTORIALONE"));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Followed a youtube tutorial but i am
Getting an error in this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

"Button cannot be resolved to a type"

I'm new to android dev so im confused. Help!

Comment: If you work in eclipse `ctrl+shift+o` resolves missing or unused imports. Although you are importing Button, so it is strange that you should get that message.

Comment: Yes, @Muhammad Nabeel Arif's answer is important

Comment: Perform a clean on your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in your xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

move your cursor to "button" in your code and select "Import button(android.widget)"..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Button definied in you main.xml layout?
Something like:

```
<Button android:text="Click me" android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I have this

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

Answer (score 0):

Had you added follwoing in your root layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    

</LinearLayout>'

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:
1. Remove the import android.R (may have been accidentally imported)
2. clean the project
3. build the project again

Answer (score -1):

Move your cursor to "button" in your code and press `ALT + Enter`

I bold at which you have to press `alt + enter`

```
Button tut1 = **(Button)** findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
```